# Firefox Addon Validation warning Access to the `ctypes` global

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I'm using jsctypes to call to NativeAPIs (C code) and it is working and valid for firefox version < 43. I validate the my Addon Jar file in Mozilla portal and it gave me the warning says

```
Access to the `ctypes` global
```

in the line of

```
ctypes.open("user32.dll")
```

and every where I call the NativeAPI

```
lib.declare("InitData")
```

Do I really care about this warning? Does the reviewer ignore this warning and pass my addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just warnings, they are very persistent warnings, so the reviewers don't accidentally miss them. You can safely ignore these messages. ctypes is powerful stuff, so it needs reviewers to look at it very closely, and the addon review team uses that same validation page as a starting point.